# How to share a music playlist containing both commercial and non-commercial recordings

Tags: audio, itunes, playlists, spotify, google-music

I want to use a music streaming service (preferably Google Music) to legally share a playlist with a 100+ member choral group.  The playlist comprises good recordings of pieces we're currently preparing for performance and, hence, will change every 3 months.

This would be relatively simple if every piece were available on GMusic (or Spotify or iTunes) but the typical situation is that only about 80% of pieces have commercially available recordings.  Decent amateur performances can often be found on YouTube for some, but not all, of the remainder.  We sometimes perform new and original works for which no recording exists anywhere; for those we usually ask our rehearsal pianist to record accompaniment tracks.

As a GMusic All Access subscriber, I can upload extra material for my own use and add it to the playlist,  but GMusic excludes it from the playlist when I share the link with others.

**I'm looking for a solution that lets me create a single playlist that provides access to all the tracks to anyone with the link.** Ideally, there would be a free, e.g. ad-supported, option for those that don't wish to take on a paid subscription. A more important consideration is that many of our singers are not sophisticated computer users so the solution needs to be something that works with minimal effort.

Comment: Have you tried soundcloud?

Answer (score 0):

[Soundcloud](http://www.soundcloud.com) let you create [playlists](https://www.google.es/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCsQFjACahUKEwifg7urne_HAhXEtRoKHaTXCtI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fhelp.soundcloud.com%2Fcustomer%2Fportal%2Farticles%2F527378-what-are-sets-how-do-i-make-them-&usg=AFQjCNEyrgoIvL_Ylf8hQxVzga8RFCmYPQ&sig2=Nh1tmEbGdJLG8igG-1A4eg&bvm=bv.102537793,d.d2s) with the music you upload, and the people who want to listen can do it from the webpage or mobile app.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  SoundCloud would work for the 10% of tracks where we create a recording, but not for the 90% that is copyrighted material.